# При попытки измены директории сохранения выскакивает ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyscript

При работе кода должен был сохранятся Qr-код в папку где находится сам HTML файл(save_dir=os.getcwd()), но не работало(при запуске в питоне работает), попытался ввести конкретный путь куда сохранять, но вывело эту ошибку.

> JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 421, in eval_code CodeRunner( File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 237, in **init** self.ast = next(self._gen) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 141, in _parse_and_compile_gen mod = compile(source, filename, mode, flags | ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "", line 15 )\ ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PyScript App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css"/>
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<py-config>
packages = ["amzqr"]
</py-config>
<py-script>
from amzqr import amzqr
import os


version, level, qr_name = amzqr.run(
    words = "Work?",
    version=10,
    level='H',
    picture=None,
    colorized=True,
    contrast=1.0,
    brightness=1.0,
    save_name=None,
    save_dir=os.getcwd()
)
</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "попытался ввести конкретный путь куда сохранять, но вывело эту ошибку" - покажите как именно пытались. Судя по ошибке, или кавычка не закрыта, или что-то подобное. Возможно обратный слеш перед кавычкой, который в итоге эту кавычку экранирует, и она считается не закрытой. "но не работало" - укажите как именно не работало, возникает ошибка или что?

Comment: Вообще, точно не могу утверждать, но по идее через скрипты в браузере не должно быть возможности получить прямой доступ к файловой системе (иначе любой сайт мог бы легко затереть папку пользователя, например). Так что по идее нужно формировать изображение в памяти, потом как-то отдавать на скачивание.

Comment: insolor прав, яваскрипт не имеет доступа к файловой системе в режиме записи. генерируя контент пытайтесь запихнуть его в ссылку вида <a href=data://base64hereisimgcontent>click</a>